# Is there any way to reconfigure middleware after startup?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In the `ConfigureServices()` method of my ASP.NET 6.0 app, I have the following

```cs
// Code has been simplified for the purposes of this example.
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;

    // Only trust "X-Forward*" headers from user-specified hosts.
    foreach (var proxy in ApplicationSettings.GetKnownProxies())
    {
      options.KnownProxies.Add(proxy);
    }
});
```

The `ApplicationSettings.GetKnownProxies()` method returns something according to what the end-user specified in the app's system configuration screen.

The problem is that the end user can change the settings during the lifetime of the application (either adding or removing proxies). However, since the "configure" code is only run on startup, any changes won't take effect until the web application is restarted.

Is there any way to avoid this? That is to say, is there any way to reconfigure the `ForwardedHeaders` feature without restarting the entire web application?

Comment: You can move the proxy configuration into a service. This service also exposes methods for manipulating the proxies. And you inject this service into your middleware to get the latest version of the proxies.

Comment: @Eldar The `ForwardedHeaders` middleware isn't mine - it's part of ASP.NET Core. So I can't alter that middleware after it's been set up, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry for that assumption but it seems configuring `ForwardedHeadersOptions` is enough to change the behavior of the middleware. So using a configuration delegate mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options) might work.

Comment: @Eldar I don't think that configuration delegate will get me any further. From what I can tell, the delegate will still only be called once, which means I don't have an opportunity to reconfigure the options after the initial call.

Comment: I have no idea if there's a built in way. But perhaps you could take [the source code for that middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ac748357e8dd2358217d5c69e08f404224f6985c/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs#L373) and fork it in order to add the dynamic behavior you're looking for. Perhaps even submit it back to Microsoft via a PR.